# Pagination with array items in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, pagination

I'd like some help if possible.

I'm having an array that contains a list of array items (think of it as a list of posts) like this:

```
$array = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit',
                'date'  => 'Tuesday 28th July 2015',
                'img_src'   => '1130x280&text=FooBar1',
            ), 
            array(
                'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit',
                'date'  => 'Friday 17th July 2015',
                'img_src'   => '350x150&text=FooBar',
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit',
                'date'  => 'Thursday 9th July 2015',
                'img_src'   => '350x150&text=FooBar',
            ),
);
```

So basicly what I want to do is try to paginate this array properly. The basic part of my code is this:

```
$per_page = 3;
$total = count($array);
        if ($total > $per_page) {

            $this->load->library('pagination');

            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
            $config['total_rows'] = $total;
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('resources/blog/');

            $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        } else {
            $offset = 0;
            $this->data['pagination'] = '';
        }
// this is the tricky part of my script
// where I need to slice the array properly each time 
if ($offset == 0) {
            $data['array'] = array_slice($array, 0, $per_page); 
        } else {
// this is probably where my mistake is **
            $this->data['array'] = array_slice($array, $per_page, $offset); 
        }
```

So basicly what I want to do is

- when I'm on the first page of the pagination ( i.e. resources/blog )
  to get the first 3 elements of my array,
- then when I move to the next pagination page ( i.e resources/blog/3 )
  to get the next 3 items,
- when I click the next page ( i.e resources/blog/6 ) the next 3 items
  etc etc..

What happens instead is on the first page I get the first 3 array items, as expected, on 2nd page I get the next 3 array items, as expected, BUT on next page I still get the same items like in 2nd page (not expected), so I guess there's something wrong with how I do the slicing in my array (check my code in **).

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value $per_page in your final line of code is always going to be 3, and so the array will always return results from the 3rd onwards after the first page. You need to update $per_page depending on what page you are on, although I think a different $value would be better as $per_page is used to state how many results are displayed per page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `$offset` changes accordingly to page number, it should be

```
$this->data['array'] = array_slice($array, $offset, $per_page);
```

because [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) second argument is offset and third is length.

Comment: Yeap! that seems to work properly! Thanks a lot for the help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$current_page = 1` and `$max_results = 10`:

```
$offset = $max_results * ($current_page - 1);
$results = array_slice($results, $offset, $max_results);
```

`$offset` is the start of the array slice and `$max_results` is the length of the slice.

This would give us a new array consisting of `$results[0]` through `$results[9]`.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you with the logic:

```
$per_page = 3;
$total_rows = count($array);
$pages = ceil($total_rows / $per_page);
$current_page = isset($_GET['i']) ? $_GET['i'] : 1;
$current_page = ($total_rows > 0) ? min($pages, $current_page) : 1;
$start = $current_page * $per_page - $per_page;

$slice = array_slice($array, $start, $per_page);
foreach ($slice as $k => $v) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($v, true) . '</pre>';
}

if ($pages > 0) {
    // Display Pagination
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is blow:

```
} else {
// this is probably where my mistake is **
$this->data['array'] = array_slice($array, $per_page, $offset); 
}
```

the function array_slice(): `array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )`, so the right way is :`$this->data['array'] = array_slice($array, $offset, $per_page);`

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as bellow.

```
    $per_page = 3;
   $total = count($array);
    if ($total > $per_page) {

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['total_rows'] = $total;
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('resources/blog/');

        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    } else {
        $offset = 0;
        $this->data['pagination'] = '';
    }
  // this is the tricky part of my script
  // where I need to slice the array properly each time 
 if ($offset == 0) {
        $data['array'] = array_slice($array, 0, $per_page); 
    } else {
    // this is probably where my mistake is **
        $startoffset=$offset - 1;
        $this->data['array'] = array_slice($array,$startoffset, $per_page); 
    }
```

It will work and will show data as per pages.